# Flickering screen Ubuntu 16.4 NVIDIA

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, screen, flicker

I'm using Ubuntu 16.4 and I have a problem from the beginning. My screen starts blinking every time I have bigger changes on the screen f.e. while logging in, opening browser, installing GPU drivers.

I've already do 3 things:

1. Install and use Kernel 4.4
   `uname-r`
   `4.4.0-139-generic`
2. Install nvidia drivers
   `nvidia-smi`
   `+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | NVIDIA-SMI 384.130                Driver Version: 384.130                |
   |-------------------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
   | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id       Disp.A |Volatile Uncorr. ECC|
   | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|        Memory-Usage |GPU-Util  Compute M.|
   |===============================+=====================+====================|
   |   0  GeForce GTX 960M    Off  |00000000:01:00.0 Off |                 N/A|
   | N/A   39C    P8    N/A /  N/A |   532MiB /  4044MiB |     5%      Default|
   +-------------------------------+---------------------+--------------------+`
3. Force fullscreen redraws using ccsm

And nothing helped!